# Using python to make a calculator. Getting an error

Tags: python, calculator

[Code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knXR7.png)

I'm trying to add an error check to my calculator but no matter what function I use, I'm getting my error message repeated back to me. Please see picture for info. Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please don't post images of code — it's useless.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

First, please don't post image code. It's really annoying
To answer your question: problem is in

```
if func != '+' or '-' ...
```

The `func!='+'` is fine, but after that you have `or '-'` means that it is always true. Just edit to:

```
if func != '+' and func != '-' ...
```

I believe you want `and`, not `or`
Or simpler, more pythonic:

```
if func not in ['+', '-', ...]
```

Hope this help. And please don't post image of code, even though your picture is quite easy to see

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please don't post image code. It makes everything so much harder. 
I think Enamoria has already answered your question about the error message.

Instead of using multiple `elif` statements, you could remove the `int()` around inputs 1 and 3and use `eval(num1+func+num2)`